# Export from AlloyDB in Composer Airflow - SSH connection difficulties

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, ssh-tunnel, google-alloydb

The issue I am encountering is how to create an SSH tunnel using IAP for AlloyDB export in Airflow hosted on Google Composer.

I am replacing a CloudSQL connection with AlloyDB. The composer environment is on a different network than my AlloyDB instance, so I know I need to use a bastion VM as listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/connect-external).

On local, I am able to port forward to my alloydb-proxy-vm and run my Airflow process. I am portforwarding in my Terminal. Thus, my VM should be properly configured.

To build the functionality into my Airflow, I tried the BashOperator like this:

```
    SSH_START = BashOperator(
        task_id='create_ssh_tunnel',
        bash_command="""
                gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/opt/airflow/np-serviceaccount.json
                gcloud config set project np-myproject
                gcloud compute ssh alloydb-psql-client \
                       --tunnel-through-iap \
                       --zone=us-central1-b \
                       --ssh-flag="-T -L 0.0.0.0:5432:localhost:5432"
                """,
        dag=dag
    )


SSH_START >> ALLOYDB_EXPORT (using PostgresTOGCSOperator)
```

However, the issue with this is that I am simply opening and closing a tunnel as a task, I am not enabling the task that needs the connection to use it.

Should I be looking to use the [ComputeEngineSSHHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/compute_ssh/index.html#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh) or something similar instead?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.